# Highlight row when select in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a sub that displays years and buttons (3 columns), I manage to make the button change on RowDataBound, but what I also want is it to be highlighted,  I had `e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 121, 139, 169)` but too hardcoded.

my dataAdapter `Select FIN_ID, FIN_Name From FinancialYears Where GetDate() >= FIN_DateStart And GetDate() <= FIN_DateEnd`

VB code:

```
Protected Sub grdFinYear_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdFinYear.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            If grdFinYear.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("FIN_ID") = FIN_ID Then
                If FIN_ID = e.Row.FindControl("hdnRecordID") Then
                    '    grdFinYear.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex
                    'End If
                    Dim activeButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
                    'e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 121, 139, 169)
                    activeButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsActiveYear"
                Else
                    Dim makeActiveButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
                    'Dim button As Button = grdFinYear.Rows(i).FindControl("btnSelect")
                    'button.Text = "MAKE THIS YEAR ACTIVE"
                    'button.Width = 175
                    makeActiveButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsMakeThisYearActive"

                End If
            End If
    End Sub
```

in HTML I have

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRecordID" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("FIN_ID") %>' />
```

Comment: In the same event above... if the row needs highlighting then go through each cell in row and change background. You could use a for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an `arraylist`

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

And keep on adding the ids for the `selected rows` afer changing color to `arraylist`

finally save it in `Session variable`

```
Session["rows"] = arr;
```

Next time when another `row` is selected

Get the `arraylist` back

```
ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)Session["rows"];
```

And loop and recolor the old rows with the new row and add the new row to `arraylist` and save it back to `session`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow & ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit))) 
    {   
       e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow;   
    }
```